# Is using interface and reflection APIs to create instances at runtime is costly option

Tags: java, performance, reflection, interface

I've have situation where the class which implements an interface need to be picked dynamically from a table. The absolute path of this class will be configured in the table. The class name will be picked from the table and then an instance of that class is created and executed using reflection API.

I'm assuming that there will be many instances created when multiple threads access this program which may eat a lot of memory and also may have a performance impact. Am I right in this assumption? Is there any way to deal with my situation here?

Following is the code snippet:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(dynamicClass);            
ServiceValidatorInterface inst = (ServiceValidatorInterface) c.newInstance();
inst.validateService(serviceDetails);
```

Comment: If you're doing a one-to-one mapping based on some input with a class output then there isn't necessarily a need to create that table at request time. As far as memory goes the instance will go out of scope once the method is left, no?

Comment: Hi Dave,
Thanks for your comment.

1. There is another program which provides the class name from a table based on some conditions. The table will have many classes configured for different purposes, but all of them implement a same interface.
2. The instance I created will be there until it is garbage collected right? I'm not sure though :)

Comment: Yes, it will be there until it's GCed. That is true of *any* JVM object regardless of how it's instantiated.

Comment: There are better ways to do this, which won’t use reflection at all.  I assume you have a limited number of classes which implement ServiceValidatorInterface.  So, create an enum (perhaps called ValidatorType), store enum values in your database (in a character field), and in your application, keep a static `Map<ValidatorType, Supplier<ValidatorType>>`.  Each Supplier value would be a constructor reference, for instance `AlbatrossServiceValidator::new`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating instances takes memory no matter how you create them, so that's not relevant to the question.

As for the performance impact, creating an instance through `newInstance()` is of course not the same as calling a constructor directly, but is it really going to make a difference for you? Also if you're going to be creating an instance of the same class over and over, you could just pool them so they're created only once. You'll just have to make sure the classes are stateless and can be shared.

Don't be too hasty in worrying about performance impact. It's 2018 and we have the most powerful computers ever seen, yet people are worried (usually without reason) ahead of time about insignificant things. The only way to know whether something has an acceptable performance is *to measure it*, and you can't do that unless you write the code first.